# Is there a difference between observation and entanglement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-interpretations

I have very basic knowledge about quantum mechanic. I started wondering if there is any difference theoretically between observation and entanglement between subject and object.

I.e. if we simplify an observer state to q-bit and initial state of second is $\alpha\left|0\right> + \beta\left|0\right>$ then observation can be roughly represented as:

$$\left|0\right> \otimes \left(\alpha\left|0\right> + \beta\left|1\right>\right) \to \alpha\left|00\right> + \beta\left|11\right>$$

(Unless I'm missing something this is unitary operation)

That should behave from 'POV' of left q-bit as-if the measurement was $\left|0\right> $ or $\left|1\right>$ respectively (sort of like in multiple worlds instead of splitting the words the observer becomes in quantum state). [Of course most scientist are represented by slightly more complex state then one q-bit ;) ]

Am I missing something or would it be a valid interpretation of quantum physics?

Comment: When I was an undergrad learning about quantum mechanics, my professor described measurement and wavefunction collapse by spreading his hands out flat to represent the wavefunction, and then swiftly bringing them together to a peak while making a *poooit* sound with his mouth. Moral of the story, if you ask a physicist what a measurement is, you may get a lot of handwaving and hot air. 

That being said, describing measurement as entanglement is the only formally sensible way to do it that I have found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The observer you model here is Wigner's friend as seen by Wigner: he may have observed something, but for Wigner he is now in a superposed state.

You are right that entanglement is the proper relationship between a quantum system and an observer, when both are described as a larger quantum system, but upon measurement (not a well defined theoretical notion unfortunately, but a very sound experimental one) entanglement is broken: measurement yields only one of the possible outcomes, and the quantum state of the observed system has to be updated accordingly.